# Why the valueOf prototype function does not work

Tags: javascript

This my code

```
let user1 = {
  valueOf() {
    console.log(20);
    return 10;
  }
};
console.log(`${user1}`); // [object Object]

// user1.__proto__.toString

let user2 = {
  toString() {
    console.log(20);
    return 10;
  }
};
console.log(+user2); // 20 10

// user2.__proto__.valueOf ?????????
```

the first time the `user1 .__ proto __. toString` function from the object prototype works.
Why the `user2.__proto__.valueOf` prototype function does not work?

Comment: It works
console.log(user1 - 4); // 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the valueOf prototype function does not work

I assume you are asking why the default `valueOf` method is not called? It is in fact called, but that's not all that happens.

When converting an object to a primitive either `toString` or `valueOf` are called. Which one is called first depends on which kind of primitive it should be converted to.

When an object is converted to a number the order is `valueOf`, `toString`. `toString` is called if `valueOf` doesn't return a primitive value. And that's the case for the default implementation of `valueOf` which returns the object itself:

```js
var obj = {};
console.log(obj.valueOf() === obj)
```

Knowing this we can verify the order in which the methods are called by implementing our own `valueOf` but returning the same value as the default one:

```js
let user2 = {
  valueOf() {
    console.log('valueOf');
    return super.valueOf();
  },
  toString() {
    console.log('toString');
    return 10;
  }
};
console.log(+user2); // 20 10
```

---

Your first example, `user1`, doesn't call `valueOf` because

1. Since the value is converted to a string, the call order of the methods is `toString`, `valueOf`.
2. The default implementation of `toString` returns a primitive value, hence the algorithm stops there and doesn't try `valueOf`.

```js
let user1 = {
  toString() {
    console.log('toString');
    return super.toString();
  },
  valueOf() {
    console.log('valueOf');
    return 10;
  }
};
console.log(`${user1}`);
```

---

Relevant parts of the spec:

- https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-toprimitive
- https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-ordinarytoprimitive
- https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-object.prototype.valueof

Answer (score 1):

Template strings format the expressions as strings, so it calls `user1.toString()`.

The unary `+` operator converts its operand to a number, which is a primitive value. So it uses `user2.valueOf()` to convert the object.